# pandas one row df import fail, index is interpreted as float

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

Here is a csv that I would like to import using pandas.

```
Isolate,Sp
14E7,indet
```

I have been unable to import the csv.  The 14E7 is interpreted as a float and so the frame cannot be imported.  Import also fails if attempting to convert it to string on import.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(infile, index_col=0, header=0, dtype=str)


#I have also tried something like these but the import does not work at all then
#converters={'Isolate': lambda x: str(x)}
#df1.index = df1.index.map(str)
```

Comment: what errors did you get, and what is the output you like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call `BUG`

***work around***

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """Isolate,Sp
14E7,indet"""

pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(txt), header=0, converters={'Isolate': str}).set_index('Isolate')

            Sp
Isolate       
14E7     indet
```